# Best way to provide the user an escape string

Tags: c#, regex, string, escaping

Suppose I want to ask a user what format they want a certain output to be in and the output will include fill-in fields.  So they provide something like this string:

```
"Output text including some field {FieldName1Value} and another {FieldName2Value} and so on..."
```

Anything bound by the {} should be a column name in a table somewhere they will be replaced with the the stored value with the code I am writing.  Seems simple, I could just do a string.Replace on any instance that matches the patter "{" + FieldName + "}".  But, what if I also want to give the user the option of using an escape so they can use brackets like any other string.  I was thinking they provide "{{" or "}}" to escape that bracket - nice and easy for them.  So, they could provide something like:

```
"Output text including some field {FieldName1Value} and another {FieldName2Value} but not this {{FieldName2Value}}"
```

But now that "{{FieldName2Value}}" is to be treated like any other string and ignored by the by the Replace.  Also, if they decided to put something like "{{{FieldName2Value}}}" with the triple brackets, that would be interpreted by the code as the field value wrapped with brackets and so on.

This is where I get stuck.  I am trying with RegEx and came up with this:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    string format = (string)values[0];
    ObservableCollection<CalloutFieldAliasMap> oc = (ObservableCollection<CalloutFieldAliasMap>)values[1];

    foreach (CalloutFieldMap map in oc)
        format = Regex.Replace(format, @"(?<!{){" + map.FieldName + "(?<!})}", " " + map.FieldAlias + " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    return format;
}
```

This works in the situation with double brackets {{ }} but NOT if there are three, ie {{{ }}}.  The triple brackets are treated like string when it should be treated as {FieldValue}.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By expanding on your regular expression, the presence of literals can be accommodated.

```
 format = Regex.Replace(format, 
      @"(?<!([^{]|^){(?:{{)*){" + Regex.Escape(map.FieldName) + "}", 
      String.Format(" {0} ", map.FieldAlias),
      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

The first part of the expression, `(?<!([^{]|^){(?:{{)*){`, designates that the `{` must be preceded by an even number of `{` characters for it to mark the beginning of a field token.  Thus, `{FieldName}` and `{{{FieldName}` will denote the start of a field name, whereas `{{FieldName}` and `{{{{FieldName}` would not.

The closing `}` simply requires that the end of the field be a simple `}`.  There is some ambiguity in the syntax in that `{FieldName1Value}}}` could be parsed as a token with `FieldName1Value` (followed by the literal `}`) or `FieldName1Value}`.  The regex assumes the former.  (If the latter is intended, you could replace this with `}(?!}(}})*)` instead.

A couple of other notes.  I added `Regex.Escape(map.FieldName)` so that all characters in the field name are treated as literals; and added the `RegexOptions.Compiled` flag.  (Since this is both a complex expression and executed in a loop, it is a good candidate for compilation.)

After the loop executes, a simple:

```
format = format.Replace("{{", "{").Replace("}}", "}")
```

can be used to unescape the literal `{{` and `}}` characters.

Comment: NICE!  You are the regex master.  Worked liked a charm. Even when using something like {{{{FieldName}}}} it correctly return {{FieldName}}. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use `String.Replace` to replace the double brackets with a character sequence that the user can not (or almost certainly will not) enter. Then do the replacement of your fields, and finally convert replacement back to the double brackets.

For example, given:

```
string replaceOpen = "{x"; // 'x' should be something like \u00ff, for example
string replaceClose = "x}";

string template = "Replace {ThisField} but not {{ThatField}}";

string temp = template.Replace("{{", replaceOpen).Replace("}}", replaceClose);
string converted = temp.Replace("{ThisField}", "Foo");

string final = converted.Replace(replaceOpen, "{{").Replace(replaceClose, "}});
```

It's not particularly pretty, but it's effective.

How you go about it is going to depend in large part on how often you call this, and how fast you really need it to be.

Comment: Thanks Jim.  This was going to be my last resort but wanted to see if there was a more, I guess you could say, "elegant" way.

Answer (score 1):

I have an extension method I wrote that almost does what you ask, but, while it does escape using double braces, it doesn't do the triple braces like you suggested.  Here is the method (also on GitHub at https://github.com/benallred/Icing/blob/master/Icing/Icing.Core/StringExtensions.cs):

```
private const string FormatTokenGroupName = "token";
private static readonly Regex FormatRegex = new Regex(@"(?<!\{)\{(?<" + FormatTokenGroupName + @">\w+)\}(?!\})", RegexOptions.Compiled);
public static string Format(this string source, IDictionary<string, string> replacements)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source) || replacements == null)
    {
        return source;
    }

    string replaced = replacements.Aggregate(source,
        (current, pair) =>
            FormatRegex.Replace(current,
                new MatchEvaluator(match =>
                    (match.Groups[FormatTokenGroupName].Value == pair.Key
                        ? pair.Value : match.Value))));

    return replaced.Replace("{{", "{").Replace("}}", "}");
}
```

Usage:

```
"This is my {FieldName}".Format(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "FieldName", "value" } });
```

Even easier if you add this:

```
public static string Format(this string source, object replacements)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source) || replacements == null)
    {
        return source;
    }

    IDictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(replacements))
    {
        string token = propertyDescriptor.Name;
        object value = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(replacements);

        replacementsDictionary.Add(token, (value != null ? value.ToString() : String.Empty));
    }

    return Format(source, replacementsDictionary);
}
```

Usage:

```
"This is my {FieldName}".Format(new { FieldName = "value" });
```

Unit tests for this method are at https://github.com/benallred/Icing/blob/master/Icing/Icing.Tests/Core/TestOf_StringExtensions.cs

**If this doesn't work, what would your ideal solution do for more than three braces?** In other words, if {{{FieldName}}} becomes {value}, what does {{{{FieldName}}}} become?  What about {{{{{FieldName}}}}} and so on?  While those cases are unlikely, they still need to be handled purposefully.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code Ben.  Yes, you last paragraph hits the nail on the head - sorry I should have articulated that better in my original post.  drf's code handels this very well.

Answer (score 0):

RegEx will not do what you want because it only knows it's current state and what transitions are available. It has no concept of memory. The language you're trying parse is not regular so you will never be able to write a RegEx to handle the general case. You would need `i` expressions where `i` is the number of matching braces.

There is a lot of theory behind this and I'll provide some links at the bottom if you're curious. But basically the language you're trying to parse is context-free and to implement a general solution you'll need model a push down automaton, which uses a stack to ensure that an opening brace has a matching closing brace (yes, this is why most languages have matching braces).

Each time you encounter `{` you put it on the stack. If you encounter `}` you pop from the stack. When you empty the stack you will know that you've reached the end of a field. Of course that's a major simplification of the problem, but if you're looking for a general solution it should get you moving in the right direction.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton